# Return only one item from the list

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I'm trying to display checkbox of some of the popular links but I face this problem. I can't return more than one item (first one). Any Ideas how to display all of them (5).

```
private getItems(){
        let items:JSX.Element;
        let data=this.state.items;
        for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          if(data[i].Title="Google"){
             items= (
              <div>
            <Checkbox
              label={data[i].Title}
              disabled={ true }
              defaultChecked={ true }
              styles={ styles }
            />
            <br/>
          </div>);
        }
        else if(data[i].Title="Yahoo"){
           items= (
           <div>
             <Checkbox
               label={data[i].Title}
               disabled={ false }
               defaultChecked={ true }
               styles={ styles }
             />
             <br/>
           </div>);
         }
         else{
           items= (
          <div>
            <Checkbox
              label={data[i].Title}
              disabled={ false }
              defaultChecked={ false }
              styles={ styles }
            />
            <br/>
          </div>);
         }
          console.log(data[i].Title);

         return items;
      } 
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit over your expected result because its not clear.

Comment: Sure, I'm expecting 5 check boxes with names of the popular search engines. First one should be Google and the user should be not allowed to change. Next checkbox should be Yahoo and it should be checked. Next 3 checkboxes should be unchecked. Receiving data from SP list - let data=this.state.items; hope this explain everything. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476075/how-to-concatenate-jsx-elements-into-an-array) to write answer:

```
let googleitem:JSX.Element;
let yahooitem:JSX.Element;
let item:JSX.Element;
let items = [];
let data=this.state.items;
for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   if(data[i].Title="Google"){
      googleitem = (your code);
   }
   else if(data[i].Title="Yahoo"){
      yahooitem = (your code);
   }
   else{
      item = (your code);
      items = [...items,item];
   }
}
items = [googleitem,yahooitem,...items];
```

May be error since I didn't use it before. But the trouble is that you must use array to store your checkboxes.

Comment: Obviously, I forgot about this detail hahaha Thanks @AlexZh!